# Transform Formulas Excel into Values Excel

Tags: python, excel-formula, openpyxl

I'm trying to generate an Excel only with values from another Excel that I create before with the same script. The main problem is that I'm trying to do it reading the Excel with the library `openpyxl` like this: `workbook = load_workbook(path, data_only=True)`, but the formulas in the Excel that I'm reading are not evaluated, so it gives me blank cells.

I found a solution, but just for Windows running Excel before reading it like this:

```
instancia = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

#hay que meter la misma ruta que la escrita en path
workbook = instancia.Workbooks.Open(path)
workbook.RefreshAll()
workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
instancia.Quit()
workbook = load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
workbook.save(new_excel_file_path)
```

I need to do the same for a linux enviroment and i dont find a way to do it.Thanks

Comment: Openpyxl doesn't use the Excel Application and doesn't evaluate formulas. Python modules that do, run Excel so Excel will update the formulas. Linux cannot run Excel